# Create an encode function using mustache templates

Tags: typescript, mustache

I'm pretty new to mustache, but my basic googling hasn't seemed to unearth anything. I'm trying to write a template for encoding in Typescript an unknown number of fields. Basically it's going to look like:

```js
encode(writer: _m0.Writer = _m0.Writer.create()) {
  writer.uint32(10).string(xx)
  writer.uint32(18).string(xx)
  writer.uint32(26).string(xx)
  ...
  etc
```

I need to increase the value in `uint32(xx)` by 8 each time. For my template so far I've got

```
  encode(writer: _m0.Writer = _m0.Writer.create()) {
    {{#fields}}
      writer.uint32().string({field}}
    {{/fields}}
  }
```

Is it possible to do what I want?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done, if you accept that some of the logic will need to be done in TypeScript.

Before I start: you need to delimit all tags with double mustaches. You should not write `.string({field}}`, but `.string({{field}}}`.

Since you are interpolating a value between the parentheses of `.uint32()`, there is only one tag that can do the job: the variable tag. I will name it `counter`:

```
.uint32({{counter}})
```

Therefore, in any case, your full template will look like this:

```
encode(writer: _m0.Writer = _m0.Writer.create()) {
  {{#fields}}
    writer.uint32({{counter}}).string({{field}}}
  {{/fields}}
}
```

Now the question remains how to ensure that `counter` exists and takes on the right value on each iteration of `{{#fields}}...{{/fields}}`. The most straightforward way is to prepare the data that you feed into the template, so that each `field` has a corresponding `counter` with the correct value:

```js
{
    fields: [{
        field: 'ab',
        counter: 10,
    }, {
        field: 'cd',
        counter: 18,
    }, {
        field: 'ef',
        counter: 26,
    }],
}
```

However, you might be looking for a way that computes the numbers automatically. In that case, [lambdas](https://jgonggrijp.gitlab.io/wontache/mustache.5.html#Variables) have your back (you need to scroll down a bit after clicking that link). For a very generic solution, start by writing a function that generates functions that return the next number in a series on each invocation:

```js
function iterate(initialValue, increment) {
    let value = initialValue;
    return function() {
        const oldValue = value;
        value += increment;
        return oldValue;
    };
}
```

Now, you can set such a function as the `counter` in the data that you pass to the template:

```js
{
    fields: [{
        field: 'ab',
    }, {
        field: 'cd',
    }, {
        field: 'ef',
    }],
    counter: iterate(10, 8),
}
```

With either approach, this would be the result:

```
encode(writer: _m0.Writer = _m0.Writer.create()) {
    writer.uint32(10).string(ab}
    writer.uint32(18).string(cd}
    writer.uint32(26).string(ef}
}
```

You can try it out in the [Wontache playground](https://jgonggrijp.gitlab.io/wontache/playground.html) by pasting the following code in its load/store box.

```
{"data":{"text":"{\n    fields: [{\n        field: 'ab',\n    }, {\n        field: 'cd',\n    }, {\n        field: 'ef',\n    }],\n    counter: (function(initialValue, increment) {\n        let value = initialValue;\n        return function() {\n            const oldValue = value;\n            value += increment;\n            return oldValue;\n        };\n    }(10, 8)),\n}"},"templates":[{"name":"encoding","text":"encode(writer: _m0.Writer = _m0.Writer.create()) {\n  {{#fields}}\n    writer.uint32({{counter}}).string({{field}}}\n  {{/fields}}\n}"}]}
```